# How to manage the "Virus Warning" alert page with WebView and WebClient for Android?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api, drive

Since google Drive can not download a file of more than 25 MB, as it requests the authorization of the user from an HTML page, I thought that it was necessary for these files to display the page "virus warning"  in a webView in my App. So I created this small sample in Android studio to test. It is quite simple a MainActivity and an activity.xml containing a simple WebView:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int WRITE_SDCARD_REQUEST_CODE = 12;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // permission to write file on internal storage ....
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    WRITE_SDCARD_REQUEST_CODE);

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    WRITE_SDCARD_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    }
    else {
        // launch my webPage and webClient withe the given url of my file
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B4fwFC8FCSQGGTZfbHYwczBXVjg");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }


}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // return after valid with "Download anyway " button
        Log.i("URL",url);//<-- url result: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=LoXi&id=0B4fwFC8FCSQGGTZfbHYwczBXVjg
        //with "confirm=LoXi" Added to the original link

        // so i try to download this new confirmed url given by Google Drive warning page
        // But the link is not valid for download!!!!! Why????
        DownloadFileFromURL dFURL = new DownloadFileFromURL();
        dFURL.execute(url);
        // I obtain a wrong file .... 36 Ko...not good!
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == WRITE_SDCARD_REQUEST_CODE)
    if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // original link of file Google drive that i want to download
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B4fwFC8FCSQXbTZfbHYwczBXVjg");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }

}


class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/video.mp4");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        //pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        //dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

}
```

}

From the download link of my file of more than 25 MB (here 90 Mo) I display well the page "Virus Warning" of drive. After clicking on the download button "download anyway" I am able to get a modified link back in my WebClient. But this link does not seem valid. If I try to copy / paste it in chrome I return to the same page of the "virus Warning" !!! Why??

When I right click on the "download anyway" button to copy the link, this link is the same form that I get by my WebClient but the part "confirm=XXXX" not, and it works and gives me access to the download!

Could you give me your opinions and suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: If I want to download a file in Drive, I usually use the webContentLink which can be obtain from a successful call to [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get). I run the link on the browser and it ends up downloading the file for me. I'm not into deep Android dev but I suggest running the webContentLink using WebView.

Comment: @noogui So you can download programaticly a file > 25MB with webContentLink  without issues?? Are you sure?

Comment: the warning will always appear if it it exceeds 25MB. I'm just saying that after you obtain the webContentLink, run it via WebView. If the warning shows, 'proceed anyway'.

Comment: The issue is the same with WebContentLink. My WebClient return a modified link after confirm by clicking "proceed anyway" that not allows me to download programaticly in my app! So we can not download files exceed 25MB even if we handle the warning and accept in our app??

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by managing the cookies in my WebViewClient and using DownloadManager:``

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // prevent other actions on page
        if (url.contains("export=download&confirm")){
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", view.getSettings().getUserAgentString());
            request.addRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, *" + "/" + "*");
            request.addRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.7,he;q=0.3");
            request.addRequestHeader("Referer", url);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/","video.mp4");
            manager.enqueue(request);
        }else {
            // a keyEvent back listener should be implemented
            myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){

    }
}
```

I hope it will help.